# Did I paraphrase this well?

Tags: past-tense, conjunctions, clauses, past-participles

Is this parsing correct?

> *I arrived at the private eye's, taken into his smoke-filled study.*

My PARSING:
I arrived at the private eye's office, and was then taken into his smoke-filled study.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, your parsing is correct.

The original that you're reading is flawed.  It ought to read, "**I arrived at the private eye's and was taken into his smoke-filled study.**"

Comment: I don't think so. See, "The boy's father, stepmom, and three other people have been arrested over the incident, charged with obstruction, false imprisonment and cruelty to children."

Comment: They aren't analogous.  Your sentence reads naturally; the OP's sentence sounds odd.

Comment: You cannot refute it grammatically, then. That is from a native speaker by the way.

Comment: Jason is correct. The sentence is not grammatical. Your parsing is grammatical; the text you're parsing is not.